# How to create a formula to look at my most recent past 20 scores in a column and averages the lowest 8 scores

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In Google Sheets I would like to create a formula to look at my most recent past 20 scores in a column and averages the lowest 8 scores.

In another post I found the following formula that will average my 8 most recent scores. However, I need it to look at my most recent 20 scores and average the lowest 8.

Here was the formula I found:

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY(SORT(K3:K, ROW(K3:K)*ISNUMBER(K3:K),0),"select * LIMIT 8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Say the dates are in column **A** starting at **A2** and the scores are in column **B** starting at **B2**.  Assume the data is not sorted in any way.

In **C2** enter:

```
=sort(B2:B26,A2:A26,false)
```

Column **C** are the scores sorted with the most recent at the top.  In **D2** enter:

```
=sort(C2:C21,1,true)
```

Column **D** are the most recent 20 scores sorted from lowest to highest.  Finally in **E2** enter:

```
=average(D2:D9)
```

This is the average of the eight lowest scorers

[image]